# Use value of one dictionary as key of another dictionary in Django?

Tags: python, django

Consider these two dictionaries:

```
a = {'f': 'foo'}
b = {'bar': 20,
     'foo': 10}
```

In Python, should I want to use the value of one dictionary as a key to another, I can do:

```
print(b[a['f']])
>>>10
```

However, in Django, I haven't been able to implement the same.
I have tried using these:

```
{{ b.{{a.f}} }}
```

which result in

> Could not parse the remainder: '{{a.f from 'b.{{a.f'

Similarly I have tried using these:

```
{{ b.{{a['f']}} }}
{{ b[a['f']] }}
{{ b[a.f] }}
```

None of them seem to work.

What should I do to implement the above said python code in Django Template Language

Comment: This is not possible (or at least not without using (custom) template filters, etc.). Django templates deliberately implement a restricted version, since you should implement such logic in the *view*, not in the template.

Comment: You might want to look into switching your Django template system to Jinaj2, which is roughly based on Django template language but allows for much more freedom as a programming language.